# invite participant in hangout

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I am creating a basic hangout API. Is it possible to send invitation to specific emails I have through API itself.

I can invite more if I want from hangout page though.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I did so, Later on I invited users through an ajax call with hangout url from hangout to my server where I am sending a mail to specific users. I guess this is best I could for the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no invitation component of either the Hangout or REST APIs, however this does not stop you from sending out emails using other means and providing the URL to the hangout.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will give it a try to send separate emails.
one more question, Can I make my hangout limited to certain participants? Participants shouldn't be able to invite others.

Comment: Unrelated questions should be asked separately.

Comment: Sorry prisoner, i couldn't get your suggestion - "Unrelated questions should be asked separately.". Though, I did to send a mail to some users related to my website activities with the hangout link from API.

Yet it's in sandbox. hope the url of hangout would work same way as in sandbox.

Comment: Your question "Can I make my hangout limited to certain participants" is best asked as another question.

Answer (score 2):

Another trick I've done is to get the URL with gapi.hangout.getHangoutUrl() and post these back to your server (or over websockets.) Then, you can create a simple url to see these "rooms." Of course, you can choose how you send those urls, so email is another solution.