# Start hangout or gchat with an initial invite in a webapplication

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

Is it possible to start a hangouts or gchat with an initial invite in a webapplication?

what i'm trying to do is have a list of people with their email addresses on a page, so what when a visitor clicks on any of them, it starts a hangout with the clicked email address invited into the hangout.

Comment: QA, please accept most appropriate answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at some level, of course.

See https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/ for more information.

Mostly Question should be based on exact problem or some undocumented behaviour, instead of just Question - whether API for the product is published. For example, in what environment or use-case you want this to happen. What makes it even more confusing is that you use term "web application".

Happy hacking!

P.S. This question looks pretty similar: [invite participant in hangout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987140/invite-participant-in-hangout?rq=1)